# Can we write a ParDo function inside a ParDo function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

For example, I have a list of URLs as strings which are stored in Datastore. 
So, I used the DatastoreIO function and read them into a PCollection. In ParDo’s DoFn, for each URL (which is a GCP cloud storage location of a file), I have to read the file present in that location and do further transformations.

So I want to know if I can write ParDo for PCollections inside a ParDo function. Kind of parallel execution of each file transformation and send KV (key, PCollection) something as output of the first ParDo function.

Sorry, if I haven't presented my scenario clearly. I'm a newbie to Apache Beam & Google Dataflow

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [TextIO#readAll()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html#readAll--).

```java
PCollection<String> urls = pipeline.apply(DatastoreIO.read(...))
PCollection<String> lines = urls.apply(TextIO.readAll())
```